# Auto adjust buttons inside panel when one button is removed during runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am having some buttons in a panel. I would like the buttons to be like the windows taskbar when one app is unpinned the space automatically get adjusted.

Currently in my panel when the user removes a button(b2) there remains a blank space between b1 and b3. I want b3 to take the blank space up.

Comment: You could use a `FlowLayoutPanel` for that.

Comment: @Brandon winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're in WinForms:

Make it a `FlowLayoutPanel` with the `FlowDirection` property set to `LeftToRight`and it will be handled automatically. If you're absolutely married to a standard `Panel` (I'm not sure why you would be), you'd have to reinvent the wheel a little bit:

```
public Form1()
{
    this.panel1.ControlRemoved += this.Panel1_ControlRemoved;
}

private void Panel1_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    int padding = 3;
    int lastRight = 0;

    foreach ( Control child in this.panel1.Controls ) 
    {
        child.Left = padding + lastRight;
        lastRight = child.Right + padding;
    }
}
```

This doesn't handle when controls are added etc... Use a `FlowLayoutPanel`.